# Hyperledger Fabric : etcdraft configuration missing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I try this tutorial
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#want-to-run-it-now

Hyperledger fabric version : 2.0 alpha

`./byfn.sh generate`
why!!! the command doesn't work....?

```
Generating certs and genesis block for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
/home/helenhdy/fabric-tuto-sample/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
org2.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x

Generate CCP files for Org1 and Org2
/home/helenhdy/fabric-tuto-sample/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
2019-10-03 11:42:47.208 KST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2019-10-03 11:42:47.241 KST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
2019-10-03 11:42:47.241 KST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:20971520
2019-10-03 11:42:47.241 KST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: /home/helenhdy/fabric-tuto-sample/fabric-samples/first-network/configtx.yaml
2019-10-03 11:42:47.270 KST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 005 orderer type: etcdraft
2019-10-03 11:42:47.271 KST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> PANI 006 etcdraft configuration missing
2019-10-03 11:42:47.271 KST [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 007 etcdraft configuration missing
panic: etcdraft configuration missing [recovered]
        panic: etcdraft configuration missing

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000edd90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00000e218, 0xc00042f604, 0xc0001e29a0, 0x1e, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc00000e218, 0xc0001e29a0, 0x1e, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panic(0xc00000e220, 0xc00042f788, 0x1, 0x1)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:73 +0x75
main.main.func1()
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/configtxgen/main.go:228 +0x1a9
panic(0xd6be40, 0xc00039eae0)
        /opt/go/go1.11.5.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000edd90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00000e1f8, 0x4, 0xe90ad8, 0x18, 0xc00042fc30, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc00000e1f8, 0xe90ad8, 0x18, 0xc00042fc30, 0x1, 0x1)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc00000e200, 0xe90ad8, 0x18, 0xc00042fc30, 0x1, 0x1)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/localconfig.(*Orderer).completeInitialization(0xc0001483f0, 0xc0002ad220, 0x3e)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:404 +0xcf3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/localconfig.(*TopLevel).completeInitialization(0xc00036e190, 0xc0002ad220, 0x3e)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:310 +0xaf
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/localconfig.LoadTopLevel(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:250 +0x4ca
main.main()
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/configtxgen/main.go:246 +0xc28
Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
```

`PANI 006 etcdraft configuration missing
PANI 007 etcdraft configuration missing`

but in configtx.yaml file
there is etcdraft configuration

```
220 Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
221
222     # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
223     OrdererType: etcdraft
224
225     Addresses:
226         - orderer.example.com:7050
```

```
309 Profiles:
310
311     TwoOrgsChannel:
312         Consortium: SampleConsortium
313         <<: *ChannelDefaults
314         Application:
315             <<: *ApplicationDefaults
316             Organizations:
317                 - *Org1
318                 - *Org2
319             Capabilities:
320                 <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
321
322     SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
323         <<: *ChannelDefaults
324         Capabilities:
325             <<: *ChannelCapabilities
326         Orderer:
327             <<: *OrdererDefaults
328             OrdererType: etcdraft
329             EtcdRaft:
330                 Consenters:
331                 - Host: orderer.example.com
332                   Port: 7050
333                   ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.c    rt
334                   ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.c    rt
335                 - Host: orderer2.example.com
336                   Port: 8050
337                   ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.    crt
338                   ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.    crt
339                 - Host: orderer3.example.com
340                   Port: 9050
341                   ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.    crt
342                   ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.    crt
343                 - Host: orderer4.example.com
344                   Port: 10050
345                   ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.    crt
346                   ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.    crt
347                 - Host: orderer5.example.com
348                   Port: 11050
349                   ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.    crt
350                   ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.    crt
351             Addresses:
352                 - orderer.example.com:7050
353                 - orderer2.example.com:8050
354                 - orderer3.example.com:9050
355                 - orderer4.example.com:10050
356                 - orderer5.example.com:11050
357
358             Organizations:
359             - *OrdererOrg
360             Capabilities:
361                 <<: *OrdererCapabilities
362         Application:
363             <<: *ApplicationDefaults
364             Organizations:
365             - <<: *OrdererOrg
366         Consortiums:
367             SampleConsortium:
368                 Organizations:
369                 - *Org1
370                 - *Org2
```

I want to know why there is error.....
or just hyperledger fabric 2.0alpha is uncomplete

Answer (score 1):

Try this Command 
`./byfn.sh generate -o etcdraft`
because by default you are generating  genesis block for solo type with **TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis** profile but that profile doesn't have consenter like **SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft** which is required because you have changed default orderer type as *etcdraft* .
Or try manually creating genesis block by this command
`../bin/configtxgen -profile SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block`

Answer (score 1):

you can see in line 225 in configtx.yaml it default contains only one orderer Address for raft you must give like below.

```
 EtcdRaft:
      Consenters:
        - Host: --------------------
          Port: --------------
          ClientTLSCert: -----------------------
          ServerTLSCert: ---------------------
```

after u check the orderer logs leader orderer is shown.